# How to get proposal list of parameters in string format method visual studio?

Tags: list, parameters, tooltip, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I use a VS 2019 Community version and don't have proposals of possible parameters like this:

[image: screenshot]

I was looking for that option in all tools settings but can't find it. Is that extra plug or resharper maybe?

In my VS I can see only this:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Please check the namespace of the file and some classes which will define this parameters. Perhaps this is due to the introduction of some external DLLS and the methods encapsulated in your own projects.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any special plugin for this. If VS doesn't give you automatically this tooltip simply you can use it `Control+Space` and it's gonna open it. Also, make sure that IntelliSense is set properly. You can find this under `Options > Text Editor` section.

Comment: Auto list members and parameter information are checked, but max information i get is general about parameter instead list of them like on the picture above.